# Protecting silverlight xap file with forms authentication - result in 2104 error

Tags: silverlight, web-config, forms-authentication, silverlight-5.0

I would like to protect my xap file, therefore in my folder /auth/ i have following web.config file

```
<security>
 <authorization>
  <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
 </authorization>
</security>
```

however, when I try to load the aspx page with the silverlight file embeded, I am receiving 
2104 error which is coupled to mime types, however Iam not even able to download the xap file, Iam getting 401.2 error. If I turn on the anonymous access, everything is working fine. Many thanks for your hints.